# Directory rewrite in .htaccess to another directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I have .htaccess that does this: `https://example.com/john` shows the contents of the directory `https://example.com/user/index.php?username=john`

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /user/index.php?username=$1 [QSA]
```

How can I make it so `https://example.com/john/blah` will show the contents of `https://example.com/user/blah`? Only show contents of `/user` folder if my previous rewrite rule was applied.

For example:

```
example.com/john/haha ---> example.com/user/haha
example.com/privacy/blah ---> // Will show 404 page because /privacy is an actual page.
```

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, edited the post. Should be `user/profile.php`

Comment: So `/john/profile` should rewrite to `/user/profile.php?username=john` ?

Comment: @anubhava I changed the post to make it more clear. I want to keep what I have so far but I also want: `/john/*` to show contents of `/user/*`, if the first rewrite rule was applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/user/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^[\w-]+/([\w-]+)$ user/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/user/$1/ -d
RewriteRule ^[\w-]+/([\w-]+)/?$ user/$1/ [L]

# existing rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ user/index.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It shows 404 not found but the file /user/blah is actually a valid file

Comment: Is `/user/blah` a valid file? I thought it is a valid directory. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is a file, not a directory

Comment: It still shows 404 page when I try to go to `/john/blah`

Comment: Can you provide your full .htaccess in question so that I can investigate it and then suggest a working solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204222/discussion-between-anubhava-and-pixie123).