# Force trailing slash and 301 redirect in existing RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a rewrite rule that shows the contents of a directory. For example, if I go to `https://www.example.com/bob/`, it will show the contents of the file `https://www.example.com/profile/index.php?username=bob`

Here is the code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/$ profile/index.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But how can I 301 redirect `https://www.example.com/bob` to `https://www.example.com/bob/` (force trailing slash)?

Answer (score 0):

You can place this rule **before** above rule to force a trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: This works but it is giving me another problem. If I go to `/login` (page, not directory) it works, but if I try to go to `/login/`, it redirects me to `/login/.php/`. If it matters, I'm also using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]` to hide .html and .php file extension

Comment: Kind of based on my question before, is it possible to force trailing slash only if my rewrite code was used? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59252408/directory-rewrite-in-htaccess-to-another-directory/59262176#comment104722678_59252408

Comment: Can you provide your full .htaccess in question so that I can investigate it and then suggest a working solution.